# c# wmi - Detecting Multiple DIMMs?

Tags: c#, wmi, hardware

As you can see in the below image, a DIMM is designated "Physical Memory 1" (and "Physical Memory 0"). Is there any way to use this to differentiate between DIMMs?

[image]

I was thinking it would be replacing the "Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory" with "Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory.Tag='Physical Memory 0'", but that did not work.

If anyone can offer any input on how to do this, thank you.

-LJM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `where` clause to limit the results returned by the WMI select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory WHERE Tag = 'Physical Memory 0'
```

MSDN has more info on how to [query WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902%28VS.85%29.aspx).